# When is $L_n-1$ a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Let $L_n$ be the $n$th Lucas number. I tested whether $L_n-1$ is prime for all $n<100000$ and found that it is prime only for $n=2,3,6,24,48,96$. Are there any other prime numbers? Also, is there a reason why most of these $n$s are in the form of $2^m\cdot3$?

We can show that $n$ must be even by these formulas for $n>3$, but they may not be useful to show that it is of the form $2^m\cdot3$:
$$L_{4k}-1=L_{6k}/L_{2k}$$
$$L_{4k+1}-1=5F_{2k}\cdot F_{2k+1}$$
$$L_{4k+2}-1=F_{6k+3}/F_{2k+1}$$
$$L_{4k+3}-1=L_{2k+1}\cdot L_{2k+2}$$

Comment: If you don't get an answer soon it might be because nobody knows.

Comment: It's easy to show that we need $3\mid n$ (otherwise, $L_n-1$ is even)

Comment: I extended the search limit to $190\ 000$. No further primes.

Comment: Still no further prime upto $n=243\ 000$

Comment: '2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 17, 16, 3, 19, 22, 11, 3, 14, 17, 1, 18, 19, 7, 26, 3, 29,' is modulo 30. Might have messed up my earlier comment ...

Comment: By the way, the analogue number $L_n+1$ has very often "small" factors. I found no prime for $n>18$ in this case. In both cases , I passed $n=300\ 000$ and aborted shortly after this limit.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for expanding the range of search. For $L_n+1$, $L_{4k}+1=F_{6k}/F_{2k}=(L_{2k}-1)(L_{2k}+1),\ L_{4k+1}+1=L_{2k}L_{2k+1},\ L_{4k+2}+1=L_{6k+3}/L_{2k+1},\ L_{4k+3}+1=5F_{2k+1}F_{2k+2}$ are hold. Because of the first formula, I think they have many small factors.

Comment: @dodicta It would be nice if you would prove your idendities since I could find them nowhere in the internet.

Comment: @Peter Some of them are from: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1988-50-181/S0025-5718-1988-0917832-6/home.html They can be shown by substituting $L_n=\phi^n+(1-\phi)^n, F_n=(\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n)/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @Peter I tried to do some numerical checks, but it wound up being very slow. What software were you using, and did you do something other than list the Lucas numbers and check for primality one by one?

Comment: I used PFGW and brute force.

Comment: $L_{2k-1}-1=L_kL_{k-1}$ for $k$ even and $L_{2k-1}-1=5F_kF_{k-1}$ for $k$ odd (see [OEIS A000032](https://oeis.org/A000032) John Blythe Dobson's 2007 note). So $n$ must be even as you already know. Also, as already commented, $n$ must be divisible by $3$ otherwise $L_{2k}-1=5F_{k}^2+2(-1)^k-1$ would be even. Therefore we need to check only $n=6k$.